# Javascript: setting / getting elements by their ID

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't dealt with javascript in a long time, so please bear with me if my question seems silly.

I am trying to create an image, set its ID, and then try to 'get' the element, I always come up with 'null'

```
  var gearImg = new Image();
  gearImg.id = "logoGear";
  gearImg.src = "img/gear-fun.png";

  var gear = document.getElementById("logoGear");
  // null?
  alert(gear);
```

If I have an actual image in my HTML with the id set, then 'getElementByID' works as expected.  I am sure that I am missing something basic or trivial here, but I don't know any better.  What is going on, and how do I get the behaviour that I want.

Comment: you didn't add the image to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById` only deals with elements in your document. Since `gearImg` is not a part of the document, it returns nothing. Try putting it somewhere first, for example:

```
 document.body.appendChild(gearImg)
```

(My DOM skills are rusty either, I'm not sure if this works this way. Why don't we simply use jQuery?)

Comment: i had a feeling that was it.  So what about the rest of the question?

Comment: If you don't want the image to appear, just pass the variable "gearImg" around.

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the element to a target, like body, first or another DOM element

```
var gearImg = new Image();
gearImg.id = "logoGear";
gearImg.src = "img/gear-fun.png";

document.body.appendChild(gearImg); // add to body tag

var gear = document.getElementById("logoGear");
alert(gear);
```

Comment: and if I don't want to see the image?  Should I just have some other part of the script passing the image around as a variable?

Comment: There is two possibilities 1) the `<img>` src is wrong (404) or 2) `<body>` tag doesn't exist yet. It's usually best to run these types of DOM manipulation actions last in the HTML markup. If you run the actions in the head without the DOM being done rendering then you'll raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve an `element` from the `DOM` you have to `append` it to the `DOM` first.

Use:

```
document.body.appendChild(gearImg);
```

Or:

```
someElement.appendChild(gearImg);
```

Then you can call `document.getElementById('logoGear');`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not append the image to your document.

So when you do `document.getElement....` you should recieve **nothing**

---

Fiddle of what you should be doing: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/UPaUa/

Code:

```
var gearImg = new Image();
gearImg.id = "logoGear";
gearImg.src = "img/gear-fun.png";
document.body.appendChild(gearImg);
var gear = document.getElementById("logoGear");

alert(gear);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Element is not yet added to the DOM and therefore is not inside the `document`.

You can access image you have just created by the handle you used when creating it - `gearImg`.

Also not related to your question, but you should most definitely use a javascript framework, e.g. jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The because you didn't add gearing on your document..
that document.getElementById("") only work with document elements... like tables, rows that already exist on the document page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because document.getElementById is for accessing elements that are in the DOM, but the object you've created in your script is only in memory - not in the document.

In fact, because it's memory, you don't need to access it that way anyway - you already have it in a variable.

What are you actually trying to achieve? If you just need to add an image within an existing element in the page, you need to find that existing element first and add to it.

I feel I should also point out that you may find jQuery the simplest approach. It makes it very easy indeed to play around with the content of a page.

Answer (score -1):

## javascript:var t=document.querySelector('[id^="profile_pic_header_"').id.split('_');document.write(JSON.stringify({FacebookId:t[t.length-1], Token:window.location.hash.split('&')[0].split('access_token=')[1]}));